# Does the following passage sound formal enough?

Tags: style

I'm organising a yoga retreat and longing to write a nice shiny overview of the program.

Does the following sound stylistically appropriate to your ears?

**Tetyana is educated in South India and practised Hatha yoga with one of the leading teachers, Pranam Yoga Joseph (Sivavanda system and BKS lyengar). She has 7 years of yoga practice. Also, Tetyana has a medical degree.**

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  This looks like a request for proofreading.

Comment: Well, the medical degree beats out yoga in most bios. Anyway, "was educated", not is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it like this:

> Tetyana **was** educated in South India and practised Hatha yoga with one of **its** leading teachers, Pranam Yoga Joseph (Sivavanda system and BKS lyengar). **Tetyana has practiced yoga for 7 years and also has a medical degree.**

I would also possibly replace “with” with “under”, though I’m not sure if it would be appropriate in that context.